# How do I set slug limit using friendly_id gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I'm using friendly_id (4.0.10.1) and this is my class:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :history]

end
```

How do I set a 49 characters limit for the slug field? The Gem works fine, it's just that I need to set this 49 limit managed by the gem and not by adding an extra step on the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Active Record validations. For example, `validates_length_of`, either on the slug itself, or if the value is coming from a column, then on the column.

Another solution is here

```
def normalize_friendly_id(string)
  super[0..49]
end
```

I found these through a Google search just now.

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/190

Comment: Thanks man!! It works for most of the scenarios. However, there's a problem when two objects try to store the same slug. In order to create a new slug by adding this "--2" to the end of the string, it ends up being a 52 characters length.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution

```
 friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

 def slug_candidates
  [
    :name,
    [:name, :city],
    [:name, :street, :city],
    [:name, :street_number, :street, :city]
  ]
 end
```

More info here  https://www.rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/FriendlyId/Slugged

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time. But maybe my example will help somebody

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  SLUG_LIMIT = 49

  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: %i[slugged finders], slug_limit: 49

  class << self
    def normalize_friendly_id(text)
      text = cut_text(text) if text.length > SLUG_LIMIT
      text.to_slug.transliterate(:russian).normalize.to_s
    end

    def cut_text(text)
      counter_string = " #{text.split(" ").pop}"
      end_index = SLUG_LIMIT - 1 - counter_string.length
      text = text[0..end_index]

      text + counter_string
    end
  end

  def slug_candidates
    [
      :name,
      %i[name slug_counter]
    ]
  end

  def slug_counter
    self.class.where("lower(name) = ?", name.downcase).count + 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).